# Performance API on mac 10.8

Tags: osx-lion, papi

Anyone tried to install papi(performance API) version 5.1.0 on the mac os 10.8 ? I am getting following errors on the make command.

```
zero_attach.c: In function ‘main’:
zero_attach.c:84: error: ‘PTRACE_ATTACH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
zero_attach.c:84: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
zero_attach.c:84: error: for each function it appears in.)
zero_attach.c:84: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘ptrace’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
zero_attach.c:117: error: ‘PTRACE_CONT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

The INSTALL.txt doesnt say anything on the mac os. Just says it can be installed no procedure given so i tried just the standard procedure mentioned.

On the main page of papi -> platform supported, it doesnt say about anything about mac os.

Do i need to install some drivers for this ? any help will be great..

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the latest version of PAPI (5.3.0) on OS X v 10.9.1.
Following the instructions in the install file did the trick too!

```
wget http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/downloads/papi-5.3.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf papi-5.3.0.tar.gz
cd papi-5.3.0/src
./configure
make
```

The only problem I encountered was with an undefined malloc.h, this is easily
fixed by either making a dummy malloc.h stub with

```
touch malloc.h
```

or copying a good malloc.h into the src directory

```
cp /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/malloc.h .
```

Then you should be fine with:

```
make
./run_tests.sh
make install
```

Happy performance counting!

p.s. I did this with gcc-4.7.3 (installed with homebrew).

Comment: I did your way.  I put inc and lib path to my makefile. but when I run my program it gives run time error dyld: Library not loaded: libpapi.dylib

Comment: @yidiyidawu That is to be expected since the makefile doesn't build the .dyld version required for OS X. You can work around this by linking with the static archive, libpapi.a. Nevertheless, I wasn't able to take actual measurements since OS X doesn't provide access to the counters, so PAPI init always fails.

Comment: I keep getting "Error: Zero Counters Available!  PAPI Won't like this!"